# Adding widgets to qtablewidget pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

Is there anyway to add like a button in qtablewidget? But the date within the cell would stil have to be displaying, for example if an user double clicked a cell, could i send a signal like a button? Thanks!

edititem():

```
def editItem(self,clicked):
    if clicked.row() == 0:
        #go to tab1
    if clicked.row() == 1:
        #go to tab1
    if clicked.row() == 2:
        #go to tab1
    if clicked.row() == 3:
        #go to tab1
```

table trigger:

```
self.table1.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.editItem)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have a couple of questions rolled into one...short answer, yes, you can add a button to a QTableWidget - you can add any widget to the table widget by calling setCellWidget:

```
# initialize a table somehow
table = QTableWidget(parent)
table.setRowCount(1)
table.setColumnCount(1)

# create an cell widget
btn = QPushButton(table)
btn.setText('12/1/12')
table.setCellWidget(0, 0, btn)
```

But that doesn't sound like what you actually want.

It sounds like you want to react to a user double-clicking one of your cells, as though they clicked a button, presumably to bring up a dialog or editor or something.

If that is the case, all you really need to do is connect to the itemDoubleClicked signal from the QTableWidget, like so:

```
def editItem(item):
    print 'editing', item.text()    

# initialize a table widget somehow
table = QTableWidget(parent)
table.setRowCount(1)
table.setColumnCount(1)

# create an item
item = QTableWidgetItem('12/1/12')
table.setItem(0, 0, item)

# if you don't want to allow in-table editing, either disable the table like:
table.setEditTriggers( QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers )

# or specifically for this item
item.setFlags( item.flags() ^ Qt.ItemIsEditable)

# create a connection to the double click event
table.itemDoubleClicked.connect(editItem)
```

Comment: How can I make the row so that when the user clicks the row is highlighted and not the individual cell.

Comment: do: table.setSelectionBehavior( QTableWidget.SelectRows )

Comment: Also, is there anyway that i can redirect to a different tab when a certain row is clicked? My question is can I basically redirect to a different tab, sort of like a hyperlink on a html webpage.

Comment: Redirect or move to a tab when a button is clicked? Any ideas.

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want really.  Link to the itemClicked signal and then modify your tab in the connected slot.  I'd need more code to go for a better answer than that.

Comment: I have added some code, for example when double clicked the signal is taken to the function editItem(), how then do i redirct to a tabe?

Comment: Well, assuming you have a tab widget somewhere with corresponding indexes, it would be something like: self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(clicked.row())

Comment: it gives me an error, i dont believe my tab has the correct indexes, `AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setCurrentIndex'`

Comment: You're setting it on the wrong widget - QWidget's don't have that property.  I'm assuming if you are trying to set a tab, then somewhere you have a Tab Widget - that's where you have to set the index value.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html  No offense, but I've answered your question, you're now on a new question - I'd post that if you're still having trouble with more code examples and not keep pushing this one into a new topic.

Comment: When I executed the first example to add a button, I couldn't not set the button to row and column that I want. It was just in (0.0). Anyone help??

Comment: @EricHulser I used your method, integrated with a for loop (Which is working fine and is used to load all data from a json file). But button gets added to only the last row? i don't know what the problem is, because the loading of data is working fine, so that means the for loop is not at fault. Can you help ?

Answer (score 2):

In PyQt4 add button to qtablewidget :

```
btn= QtGui.QPushButton('Hello')
qtable_name.setCellWidget(0,0, btn) # qtable_name is your qtablewidget name
```